# MySQL Select distinct column A from table where column B exists or if none with column B then latest based on column C

Tags: mysql, sql, select

I have the following data in a table:

```
Column A, Column B, Column C
ABC     , XYZ     , 1/1/2019
DEF     , null    , 1/1/2019
DEF     , UVW     , 1/2/2019
DEF     , null    , 1/3/2019
GHI     , null    , 1/1/2019
GHI     , null    , 1/3/2019
```

I want column A where either column B has value or simply the last occurrence. The results fporm the above table should be:

```
ABC, XYZ, 1/1/2019
DEF, UVW, 1/2/2019
GHI. null, 1/3/2019
```

Thank you,
Sammer

Answer (score 1):

If *any* value will do, use aggregation:

```
select a, max(b), max(c)
from t
group by a;
```

If you want the last non-`NULL` value and `c` is unique, then:

```
select t.*
from t
where t.c = (select t2.c
             from t t2
             where t2.a = t.a
             order by (t2.b is not null) desc, t.c desc
             limit 1
            );
```

If `c` has duplicates and you are using MySQL 8+, then you can also do:

```
select t.*
from (select t.*
             row_number() over (partition by a
                                order by (b is not null) desc, c desc
                               ) as seqnum
      from t
     ) t
where seqnum = 1;
```